# Spring framework request scope and autowiring of singletons

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using OncePerRequestFilter for a service bean in "request" scope that is autowired into controller. But I still get this error.

> Error creating bean with name
>   'fileProcessingService': Scope
>   'request' is not active for the
>   current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you
>   intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   thread-bound request found: Are you
>   referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or
>   processing a request outside of the
>   originally receiving thread?

Can a bean in request scope be injected with singleton beans ? or the problem is somewhere else ?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use request and session scoped beans outside of `DispatcherServlet`, add the following to `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: thanks, but as I said, I'm using OncePerRequestFilter / RequestContextFilter already in my web.xml. I can't use any listener in my application unfortunately. The filter is an alternative to requestContextListener.

Comment: @lisak: I can't understand how `OncePerRequestFilter` (which, as you said, you use) is related to `RequestContextFilter`. If you can't use listener, you need to use `RequestContextFilter` and place its mapping above the mapping of your filter in `web.xml`.

Comment: Sorry I meant RequestContextFilter, it extends OncePerRequestFilter so it kinda is OncePerRequestFilter. Anyway neither works. Does the order of filter mappings matter ? Cause I had it as the last filter in the web.xml. Never mind man, I worked it around.

Comment: Anyway, this was the correct answer for me. Maybe you mark it as such, so that it helps other users...?